# Grunt/jshint - task watcher terminal output colors

Tags: terminal, gruntjs, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

I'm using Grunt task runner to build a web app on Windows 8.1, and have JShint task for checking Javascript. The Gruntfile was generated using the Webapp generator.

When JSHint detects an error, the output generated in the terminal window is colored navy blue - which is very difficult to read against the black background color of the terminal window.

I have tried to change the background color to something else, but while it fixes the JShint output, it makes other output hard to read.

So my question is; how do I change the color of the JSHint output?

Comment: I experience the same problem. Here's a screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/v0u4awbr1/. The offending output appears to be warnings.

Answer (score 5):

I found this question when trying to do the same thing.  One thing that you can try is using the no-color flag.  Run like this:

```
grunt jshint --no-color
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will remove all colors - which makes it even worse, IMO.

This apparently is to do with how grunt log output works. See this thread [grunt.log color configuration](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1128#issuecomment-41758518)

So, seems like the there are no other options for us Windows users. I have been meaning to try Cygwin terminal to see if that makes any difference...will report back with what I find.

Comment: Had a look into using Cygwin with grunt, and it looks way too much effort. I'm giving up and sticking to powershell.

Comment: @zumek - How about an upvote for a partial solution?